# Who | awk Bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

I am receiving the following error when attempting to run my script:

```
./watchuser: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
./watchuser: line 12: `echo ("$User online since:" who| awk ' { print "User: " $1" -    Terminal: "$2" - Login @ " $3" "$4}') '
```

Here is my script, it is supposed to show users that are online in Epoch format.

```
#!/bin/bash
for User in $(cd /home;ls --hide=lost+found)do
echo ("$User online since:" who| awk ' { print "User: " $1" - Terminal: "$2" - $
NOW=$ ( date +%s -d "Jan 1, 1980 00:00:01")
USR=$ ( who |awk ' {print $1, ":",$5,$6,$9 } ' | grep $U)
USRDATE=$(echo $USR | cut -d ":" -f2)
(( USRDATE = $(date --date "$USRDATE" +%s) / 86400 ))
(( NOW = NOW/86400 ))
(( DAYS = NOW - USRDATE ))
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course you receive errors. Your script is a mess. I can't understand exactly what you intend to do, but maybe this variant will give you an  idea where are you wrong:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for User in $(cd /home;ls --hide=lost+found); do
    echo "$User online since:" 
    who | awk '{ print "\tUser: "$1" - Terminal: "$2" - "$3" "$4}'
    NOW=$(date +%s -d "Jan 1, 1980 00:00:01")
    USR=$(lastlog |awk ' {print $1, ":",$5,$6,$9 } ' | grep $User)
    USRDATE=$(echo $USR | cut -d ":" -f2)
    (( USRDATE = $(date --date "$USRDATE" +%s) / 86400 ))
    (( NOW = NOW/86400 ))
    (( DAYS = NOW - USRDATE ))
done
```

Comment: I am trying to get a report of users that are logged in and for how many seconds.

Comment: @Macenbro Ok, try, but please, without syntax errors, eventually read some tutorials about bash and use `man <command>` when you don't know something about a command.  Also, before to use your commands in script, test those commands in terminal.

Comment: well, I still get syntax errors with your corrections, but what can we do :P. You did something heroic just figuring out what OP wanted.